# Computational time of qr, svd and eig in MATLAB?

Tags: numerical-methods, matlab

How does the time for qr depend on the dimensions of the matrix m and n (does it depend on on the type of linear systems: overdetermined and underdetermined?) How about svd and eig? Does the time depend on whether you ask only for the eigenvalues (as in E=eig(A)) or also for the eigenvectors (as in [V,E]=eig(A))?I tried to do that using tic and toc, but couldn't find any relationship between the computational time and m,n...

Comment: You may want to try `timeit` to get more reliable timing information.

Comment: Matlab uses lapack routines (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/double/) ; algorithm "eig" for example is surely fairly complex with many "forks" according to the cases at hand.

Comment: Do you mean the asymptotic complexity of these algorithms as $m$ and $n$ go to infinity, or the real world times you will see on your laptop for small $m$ and $n$?

Comment: @tch, I would appreciate, if you could tell both...